# How to create a constructor that takes an array parameter and initialise the values in an underlying array?

Tags: java, arrays, constructor, initialization

How to create a constructor that takes an array parameter and initialize the values in an underlying array in Java?

The constructor should do so such that when I call it in main, passing it an array as a parameter, the initialized object that is output by the constructor is the same as the array parameter.

```
public class MyClass<E> {

protected E[] underlyingArray;

public MyClass(Object[] arr) {
     underlyingArray = (E[]) new Object[arr.length];
     for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          this.underlyingArray[i] = (E) arr[i];
     }
}

public void print() {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + ": " + underlyingArray[i]);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
final String[] array = { "d", "e", "f" };
final MyClass myArray = new MyClass((Object[])array);
myArray.print();
```

Expected:

```
0: d
1: e
2: f
```

Actual:
I get an index out of bounds exception as `myArray` was never initialized after passing `arr` through `myClass` constructor.

I have tried several combinations in `MyClass` constructor but have not been able to initialize the underlying array `myArray` successfully.

Comment: How `print()` look like

Comment: If one makes a reasonable assumption of what `print` is, that works just fine.

Comment: *"Actual: I get an index out of bounds exception as myArray was never initialized after passing arr through myClass constructor."* No, if `myArray` were uninitialized, you wouldn't get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, you'd get a compilation error (or depending on your definition of "uninitialized", a `NullPointerException`). No, it appears that in `print`, you're going out of bounds.

Comment: This is more or less what Josh Bloch discusses in Effective Java, refer to https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2861454&seqNum=4.

Answer (score 2):

The code works, but there is no need of generics in your case

```
class MyClass {

private Object[] underlyingArray;

MyClass(Object[] arr) {
    underlyingArray = new Object[arr.length];
    for (int index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
        this.underlyingArray[index] = arr[index];
    }

}

public void print() {
    for (int index = 0; index < underlyingArray.length; index++) {
        System.out.println(index + " : " + underlyingArray[index]);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String[] array = { "d", "e", "f" };
    final MyClass myArray = new MyClass(array);
    myArray.print();
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code works just fine. Check your `print()`method. This works for me.

```
public class MyClass<E> {
    protected E[] underlyingArray;
    public MyClass(Object[] arr) {
        underlyingArray = (E[]) new Object[arr.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            this.underlyingArray[i] = (E) arr[i];
        }
    }    
     public void print(){
        for(int i=0;i<underlyingArray.length;i++){
            System.out.println(i+": "+underlyingArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String[] array = { "d", "e", "f" };
    final MyClass myArray = new MyClass((Object[])array);
    myArray.print();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks everyone, the reason why my code did not work was because of an additional `size` variable that I did not set (not included in snippet) as part of initialization of the constructor. That explains the indexOutOfBounds exception I got as the `size` was always 0.

Apologies for raising a question with incomplete information. The code does work fine in the snippet above. Deserved the downvote. Thanks again.